# ¿Cómo obtengo el valor de "Group by" relacionado?

Tags: sql-server

Tengo una tabla con muchos registros "duplicados" aparentemente, que necesito agrupar por `COL_ALI` con la `FECHA_ALTA` más reciente.

Sin embargo, no sé qué hacer con `COL_NOMBRE`. Necesito traer el nombre que le equivale a ese registro con la última fecha.

Como se puede ver en el resultado, la fecha de `EQUAL` no es la que le corresponde (sí, ya sé que es porque tiene el `MIN(COLABS.COL_NOMBRE) AS COL_NOMBRE)` pero entonces, ¿cómo relaciono el valor que le corresponde?

Consulta de prueba:

```
SELECT 
        COLABS.COL_ID,      
        MIN(COLABS.COL_NOMBRE) AS COL_NOMBRE,
        MAX(COLABS.FC_ALTA) AS FECHA_ALTA

FROM dbo.COLABS

GROUP BY COLABS.COL_ID
```

Tabla

```
    COL_ALI |COL_NOMBRE |   FECHA_ALTA
--------------------------------------------
    RQS555  |SONICS    | 2014-08-15 00:00:00.000
    RQS555  |LANI      | 2016-08-27 00:00:00.000
    RQS555  |EQUAL     | 2016-08-23 00:00:00.000
```

Resultado obtenido

```
    COL_ALI | CIA_NOMBRE    | FECHA_ALTA
-----------------------------------------
    RQS555  | EQUAL         | 2016-08-27 00:00:00.000
```

Resultado esperado

```
    COL_ALI | CIA_NOMBRE    | FECHA_ALTA
-------------------------------------------
    RQS555  | LANI          | 2016-08-27 00:00:00.000
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/981c5/4/0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
   SELECT *,
          RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY COL_ALI ORDER BY FECHA_ALTA DESC)
   FROM dbo.COLABS
)
SELECT COL_ALI,
       CIA_NOMBRE,
       FECHA_ALTA
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1;
```

Comment: Gracias a los todos por sus respuestas, las dos me funcionarón correctamente, pero con la consulta de @fedorqui tarda un poco más en dar los resultados, mientras que con la consulta de Lamak es más rápido, por tal optaré por usar la consulta de Lamak en términos de rendimiento.

Answer (score 2):

Lo que ocurre es que no puedes hacer la consulta directamente. En lugar de eso, debes cargar el máximo y a continuación combinar la tabla con ese resultado:

```
SELECT t.COL_ALI, t.COL_NOMBRE, r.MAX_FECHA
FROM (
  SELECT
        COL_ALI, MAX(FECHA_ALTA) AS MAX_FECHA
        FROM COLABS
        GROUP BY COL_ALI
  ) r
INNER JOIN COLABS t
ON t.COL_ALI = r.COL_ALI AND t.FECHA_ALTA = r.MAX_FECHA
```

Basado en [GROUP BY with MAX(DATE)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3491386/1983854) y probado en http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/981c5/7